# CSS :after working but not when editing from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My CSS looks like:

```
/* works */
.badger-left:after {
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 0;
    background: #428bca;
}
```

jQuery to change it on the fly:

```
$('.badger-left:after').css('background-color', "red"); // doesnt work
$('.badger-left').attr({ 'data-badger': "USA" }); // works
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-sm-12 badger-left" data-badger="">


  </div>
```

Why isn't the jQuery selector working and what should I do to make it work?
http://screencast.com/t/onWs4KDJVD -- where it says "USA" (USA is set from the attr. data-badger in jquery), that background needs to change to red (or whatever color specified) via jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery selectors doesn't pseudo-elements.

Comment: jQuery cannot interact with `:after` because the element doesn't really exist. (duplicate?)

Comment: jQuery (and javascript in general) does ***not*** support pseudo classes.

Comment: Oh! What should I do ? I also tried el.after().css(), but that changes the whole div

Comment: The only thing you can do is make this change using a class change instead of .css

Comment: Since :after and :before can't be selected, could you post what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, added an image.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selectors :after and :before is not supported in javascript, most pseudo-classes are not.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery adds the css inline. Since :before, and :after do not really exist there is no style attribute to place the css into anyway.

Run this test to see:

```
$("*:after") // returns []
$("*") // returns a huge array ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either a jQuery .append() or .add() to achieve a similar effect.

The CSS ::after selector just adds an "imaginary" div to the inside of the element it's applied to just before the closing tag.

**.append()**

https://api.jquery.com/append/

**.add()**

https://api.jquery.com/add/

**jQuery:**

```
$('.badger-left').append('div');
```

**CSS:**

```
.badger-left div{
    /* ".badger-left::after" styling would go here */
}
```